# Does the word "accommodate" come with the meaning of "provide" or "adapt"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality

I'm a little bit confused with the word "accommodate", since that the common usage is "to provide lodging or sufficient space ...", but I found out there's another meaning of this word is "to provide something with desired or needed". So I wrote a paragraph of a product page with using the phrase "accommodate...with..." for a substitute of "providing...with". Can I write "This unique product accommodate certain models with greater extend of its applications."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the correct word -- provide; don't substitute a fancy or longer word for a simpler one just to make your writing sound better. It's far more important to be clear (especially on product pages).

With that said, just because a word is a synonym, that doesn't mean that it's used in the same way. The word *accommodate*, for example, is rarely (if ever?) used with the word *with*.

Examples of correct usage:

- She asked to borrow my luggage, and I agreed to accommodate her request.
- I try to be accommodating, but sometimes I have to insist on my own needs.
- He asked me to buy apples, and I was happy to accommodate him.

I think that you are trying to say that the product offers certain models (of another product) increased functionality. If so, you might consider constructions such as:

- This unique product accommodates a wide range of applications.
- The extent of the applications available to certain models is greatly increased with this unique product.
- This unique product provides certain models with a breadth of applications.

Again, this assumes that "certain models" applies to something *other* than the "unique product." If you are talking about certain models *of the unique product itself*, then I have misinterpreted your sentence, and we will need additional clarification about your intent.

Comment: I totally agree what you've said at the beginning, to use simpler words for clearer description on product page. But I bet you wouldn't like to read a paragraph with a word repeat again and again. And that's why I'm searching for substitute words.

Comment: @Murphy And we are happy to "accommodate." :-)